# Node.js - trouble with path module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes, package.json

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const getAllFiles = function (dirPath, arrayOfFiles) {
  files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

  arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || [];

  files.forEach((file) => {
    if (fs.statSync(`${dirPath}/${file}`).isDirectory()) {
      arrayOfFiles = getAllFiles(`${dirPath}/${file}`, arrayOfFiles);
    } else {
      arrayOfFiles.push(path.join(__dirname, dirPath, '/', file));
    }
  });

  console.log(arrayOfFiles);
};

getAllFiles('D:/JS/ProjectX');
```

return error:

[image]

Probably, I think, that is a problem with my package.json. I have installed path, all my package.json installed globaly. Somebady help my or explain where is a problem ?

Comment: Which line is line 82 in your project?

Comment: Also, you don't need to install `path`; it's built into NodeJS.

Comment: It's telling you that `arrayOfFiles` is `undefined`. This is because your function doesn't return anything but you're calling it recursively

Comment: line 82 contains ```arrayOfFiles.push(path.join(__dirname, dirPath, '/', file));```